# Flask sqlalchemy cannot insert data in mysql

Tags: python, mysql, flask, sqlalchemy

I tried to create table and insert data into it in mysql, while create table is succeed and unable to insert data,does anyone knows how to fix it ,thanks much in advance..

```
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Article(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'ar'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    content = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)

db.create_all()

@app.route('/')

def hello_world():

    article1 = Article(title='aaa',content='bbb')
    db.session.add(article1)
    db.session.commit()
```

the table is actually created, but the data is still not inserted..

```
mysql> desc ar;

+---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field   | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id      | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| title   | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| content | text         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
3 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> select * from ar;

Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to navigate to the app route in the browser for the code to run, Also in the app route, return a value.

I hope you missed the return statement for the sake of illustration.

I hope this helps.

Comment: @chenhanzhu Did you load the route in the browser ?

Comment: @IljaEverilä Sorry I missed out that.

Comment: @chenhanzhu You need to navigate to the route in the browser for the code to run, Also in the app route, return a value. I hope you missed the return statement for the sake of illustration. I hope this helps.